# In bxslider moveslide is not working properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bxslider

In bxslider i want to move one slide at a time on clicking on some label but one slide is not moving at a time. Please help me if anybody can?

## aspx code:

```
<p><span id="slider-prev"></span> | <span id="slider-next"></span></p>
<ul class="trend-products">
   <li><img src="../images/postad.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="../images/postad.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="../images/postad.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="../images/postad.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="../images/postad.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="../images/postad.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

## jQuery:

```
$('.trend-products').bxSlider({
    auto:false,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 20,
    slideWidth: 170,
    slideMargin: 10,
    controls: true,
    moveSlides: 1,
    pager: false,
    nextSelector: '#slider-next',
    prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
    nextText: 'Onward →',
    prevText: '← Go back'
});
```

Comment: not actually. in my slider there are multiple slides and slides should move one at a time like this http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified#example4

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3RM/596/

Comment: yeah i wanna do it that way buy my code is not working properly. sometimes it move one slide at a time and sometimes it move many at a time or go to first slide on random basis.

Comment: got it working properly jquery 2.1.0 was the problem replaced with jquery 1.9.1